# Are there any downsides to using the object name directly (and not the this keyword) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var myObj = {
    // Case 1
    myFunc1: function() {...},
   
    // Case 2
    myFunc2: function() {
        console.log(this.myFunc1);

        console.log(myObj.myFunc1);
    }
}
```

In both cases, the result is the same. Now my question is this: are there any downsides to using `myObj.myFunc1()` always? I don't like using the `this` keyword, and there are often unexpected issues which I can't wrap my head around. If I just use my object's name to directly call the function, what sort of unexpected edge cases can I face?

Comment: In this simple code no. But it is a shame your preference is to work around "something you don't like" rather than learn how the language actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `this` and `without this` ways are avialable, but they do different things when it comes to inheritance with an overridden static method. Choose the one whose behavior you expect:

```
class Profile {
  static Admin() {
    return "Admin";
  }
  usernameA() {
    console.log(Prfile.Admin());
  }
  usernameB() {
    console.log(this.constructor.Admin());
  }
}
class SubProfile extends Profile {
  static Admin() {
    return "SubProfile";
  }
}
new SubProfile ().usernameA(); // Profile
new SubProfile ().usernameB(); // SubProfile
```

Dependent to static property via the class will be actually static and constantly give the same value. Using `this.constructor` instead will use dynamic dispatch and refer to the class of the current instance, where the static property **should** have the inherited value but could also be overridden.

If you expect static properties not to be overridden, use the explicit reference.

Comment: Thank you for that descriptive answer. So in other words, as long as I don't want to use OOP, and instead use this object as just a namespace, I should be using the explicit reference. Did I get that right?

Answer (score 3):

This really gets down to OOP and instance vs static methods.

For static methods, the result should be the same. For instance methods, function results may differ based on which instance of the object you have and the state of those objects.

You might want to read through this, it can explain in much more detail than I can add here:

https://abdulapopoola.com/2013/03/30/static-and-instance-methods-in-javascript/